# Wordpress: Relate blog post to a (sub)page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I’ve a question about Wordpress’ post and pages. I’m not new to Wordpress but this feature is a first for me and I can’t really seem to get my head around it.

The case is, that I have a parent page (**focusareas**) which has a number of static childrens (**child01**, **child02**, **child03**, etc.) These children are as mentioned static and do not change (or change very little over time) but the thing is that there will be some blog posts which are related to them – but the blog posts also have to function as an independent entity. Each blog post can have a number of comments, but the child01, 02, 03, … n subpages cannot have comments.

Is it possible to “connect” or “relate” a blog post to a page (subpage) and list them on the subpage?

I don’t know if I’ve explained it correctly but otherwise please let me know and I’ll draw a diagram or explain in further details.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 1):

I think you need 2 things.

The first is use custom fields to store wich posts ( or category, or anything else ) is related to this page. http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

The second is use get_posts loop, to "call" these posts inside other loop, with all his features: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: you mean to use the custom field in the page or in the post? is there a way to connect the post to the pages without using categories but just an identifier of the page?

Comment: You can connect the post to the page by adding a custom field to post (which indicates the post it's related).